# syntax wbdp -> update with complex where clause

Tags: wordpress

I can't figure the syntax for this request :

```
UPDATE my_table SET is_read ='1' WHERE my_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

'my_date
for using with `wpdb-> update`

I have this :

`wpdb->update('my_table', array('is_read' => '1'), array('my_date',` ... and then I don't know

Need some help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Example to use SQL queries directly with wpdb:

```
       function setAsRead($days_interval){
            global $wpdb;

              $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE my_table SET 
                        is_read ='1' WHERE my_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %d DAY)",
                        $days_interval));

               return $result;
            }

            //use
            setAsRead(2);
```